# Is there a way to check automatically firestore data every hour?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

I would like my users to update a data daily and if they do not do so at midnight, a default value should be added. For that I also need to take into account time zones. For this project i'm using Firebase and ionic 4

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways to do this.  One might be a scheduled Cloud Function. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: Thank you very much